# How to design database for User table which contains address?

Tags: sql, database

I want to create a **`User`** table which contains `address` field as well and the `address` is a user defined class which further contains fields

Now the situation is like this :

1. User class contains the address object
2. Address is not a string but user class which contains various fields

contents of **class User**:

```
class User
{
private String name;
private int id;
private Address address;
private String martial_status;
private String employed_status;
private Date createdate;
```

Contents of **Address class**:

```
class Address
{
private String hno;
private String street;
private String city;
private int zip;
private String state;
private String country;
```

How do I design database for such a scenario, if I create separate `User` and `Address` tables, how will I refer to `address` field in `user` table?

Comment: Create an auto-generated primary key `Id` or 'AddressId' in `Address` table and refer that in `User` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Single table - each row has user and address data

SQL-wise, If each user has an address - keep both in the same table. This approach will save you unnecessary, and potentially erroneous, `JOIN` operations. When you query, you will have to split each row in the result into two classes.

## Different `user` and `address` tables

If only a few user have addresses, or if the same address might be shared with many users, build two table and JOIN them with a reference from the `user` table to a primary key in the `address` table. Each table will be associated with its own class.

This means that the `address` table has a primary key, usually a unique numeric `id`. The `user` table has an `address_id` field, whose value is a valid `address.id` value.

For example,

```
address
| id        | ...    |  city          |
| 1         | ...    |  Sausalito     |
| 1         | ...    |  San Francisco |

user
| name           |  ...   |  address_id |
| George Carlin  |  ...   |  1          |
| Richard Pryor  |  ...   |  2          |
```

Means that George Carlin lives in Sausalito, and Richard Pryor lives in San Francisco.

There are other restrictions you can impose. For example making each address id unique in the user table (so that two users can't have the same address), or a non-null constraint which enforces each user to have an address.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get the two table approach , can you help with some code ?

Comment: It's not clear, adress table has the same id twice. Moreover the same adress is not shared with many users.

Answer (score 2):

You have some possibilities, depending on situation:

1- Adam's scenarios #1, if user has just an address, keep data in the same table. I.e.

```
            create table user
            ( ID number not null primary key,
              ...other user fields...
              street varchar(100),
              ...other address fields
              );
```

2- Adam Scenario #2, address shared by several users, in 2 separate tables

```
            create table user
            ( id number not null primary key,
              ...other user fields...
              **address_id number foreign key references address(id)**
             );


             create table address
            ( **id number not null primary key**,
              ...other address fields...
             );
```

3- One user may have several addresses. In this case you've a foreign key in table address, referencing user

```
            create table user
            ( id number not null primary key,
              ...other user fields...

             );


             create table address
            ( **id number not null primary key**,
              ...other address fields...
              **user_id not null foreign key references user(id)**
             );
```

4- many user, having many addressess , with users that can by sharing some addresses, in this case you have a connection table with references both user and address table.

```
            create table user
            ( id number not null primary key,
              ...other user fields...
             );


             create table address
            ( **id number not null primary key**,
              ...other address fields...
             );

             create table user_address(
                **user_id number foreign key references user(id)**,
                **address_id number foreign key references address(id)**,
                constraint user_address_pk primary key (user_id,address_id)
             );
```

5- In case 1, you may possibly want to mantain a one-to one relation, but i think is not the case.

I normally use scenario 3

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a TYPE in SQL for storing address

eg.

```
DECLARE 
TYPE address IS RECORD 
(
    address_id number(5), 
    address_hno varchar(20),
    address_street varchar(100),
    address_city varchar(50),
    address_zip varchar(20),
    address_state varchar(100),
    address_country varchar(100)
)
```

You can use this type while creating a user table and refer this TYPE instead of pre-defined datatypes.

Hope this helps.